# Partial link in MS Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-c++, build-process, static-linking

I am trying to reduce link time when building a large C++ application in MS Visual Studio 2005. My link time is currently 7 to 100 seconds, usually closer to 7 (but it seems to depend on luck).

My application consists of about 20 static libraries, one of which is large, rarely changes and depends on a large third-party library, which is not used by any of my other libs. I think it is a classic case where **partial link** will improve build times. By "partial link" i mean whatever `ld -r` does on Linux.

Is "partial link" possible with MS Visual Studio? I didn't find it in their documentation, but maybe they call it a different name, or maybe it's a hidden feature.

Does my speculation on partial link make sense? Is there really a chance it will help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [linking incrementally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VC.PROJECT.VCLINKERTOOL.LINKINCREMENTAL%29&rd=true) via the `/INCREMENTAL` switch what you are looking for?

One other thing you can do is to go through an extra level of indirection: Wrap the static libs into a DLL and expose whatever is used by the application via the DLL. That DLL could then be built fairly infrequently and linking with it may be far less expensive.

Comment: I already use incremental linking. If this is equivalent to what i am asking for, i am out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem trivial, but the solution in my case was using a *module definition file* (`foo.def`).
The [file format specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h%28VS.80%29.aspx) by Microsoft implies that it should be used only for DLL files, <strike>but it works perfectly well for static libraries too</strike> **so i had to change my library into a DLL**.

This reduced my minimal link time from 7 to 2 seconds (probably helped the average link time too).